# add and remove tags on a list

Tags: usability, tags

I'm building a tag generator. I think users should not enter/select a tag that has already been selected and users should be able to create new tags by pressing enter.

Here: 
https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ 
is always only a selection from a list of available. Once a value is selected it becomes disabled in the suggestion list - which for me seems great.

On the other way,
I was thinking that users could just type and click enter to create tags. But if they have a typo or misspelling then that tag lives on forever? 
Jira has a control with a check and an X

[image]

What is the best way (or less annoying)? 
It wouldn't be frustrating if you had to click on the check every time you wanted to had a new tag (or a group of them), for instance... but It would be problematic if you had a massive amount of non-usable tags also...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An idea is **stack-overflow tags**. While you type your tag, you can see the available tags and the number of times that they have been used.

What is good about this implementation

- It is very easy to use
- The user can create their own tags
- The user can see the already made tags
- The user can see how much these tags have been used

[image: Stack-overflow tags]

Creating a new tag in stack-overflow. You could also add a notification message that a new tag has been created.

[image]

Comment: But you can't have tags that don't exist already... In my case, the user should be able to create tags. And the question is: having the check button for the user to confirm the submission or every time the user inserts a tag it goes to the tags list (even if it was misspelled)...

Comment: @AnaNeto Stack-overflow allows you to have tags that they don't exist, as you can see in the image that I added. Then the user sees that they have just created a new tag. Why would you like them to confirm the submission? They will know it already that their tag does not exist.

Comment: Imagine you type 'nwe tag' and submit it. It will be stored in the system forever. And everytime someone type 'n' the 'nwe tag' will appear as a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to give visual indication when a user is creating new tag.

For example, User is creating a tag called 'design' which does not exist in the system. So when user enters the word 'design', system can show user the word design as tag suggestion with a visual indicator as (new tag) against it. Check following image.

[image]

Using a simple label as 'new tag' (you can use 'create tag' also) user will get to know that he/she is creating a new tag which does not already exist in system. Plus this would be on the fly and user does not need to have any additional confirmation or clicking any button.

And as for already selected tags, such tags can appear as disabled in the tag suggestion list. Also I agree that a close (x) button is needed to remove the selected tag.